# How do you query a web browser for CSS Grid support?

Tags: css, html, css-grid

How do I query a web browser for CSS Grid support?

All major browsers support CSS Grid with recent versions, but I need to fallback to something else if a client has an older version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS you can use this:

```
@supports (display: grid) {
    /* css styles for css grid */
}
```

The @supports syntax works back to Chrome 28, Edge 20, Firefox 22, Opera 12, Safari 9 according to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports).

Internet Explorer is not listed to support the @supports syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> Say for example you want to display a message when a CSS feature is not supported.

```
<div class="message">
 Your browser does not support CSS grid 
</div>

@supports (display: grid) {
 .message { display: none }
}
```

With the feature query `@supports` above we say: *If the browser supports that css feature, then hide the message*

You can also use `@supports not(...)` or even combine more than 1 rule: `@supports (display: table-cell) and (display: list-item)`

It's worth it to take a look at [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)